# Replace Substring with Wildcard Char in String, possibly using regex Swift 3

Tags: regex, swift, swift3

As the title suggests I need to replace a substring in a string with a new string. The complication is that the substring to replace can contain a wildcard character.

eg
I have a string that can be "IAmAString6ContainingChars" or "IAmAString7ContainingChars" or "IAmAString8ContainingChars" etc. Basically there is no whitespace but there is a number in it that can be anything between 1 and 1000 or can be an empty string ie "" instead of 0

I need to replace "String[Num]Chars" with another string eg "replaced"

I assume I can use

```
var replaced = (startString as NSString).replacingOccurrences(of: regex, with: "replaced", .regularExpression)
```

But what would the regex be?

Thanks

Comment: So you are asking for a regular expression which matches zero or more decimal digits?

Comment: I'm completely new to regex but I need to match a string that always starts and ends the same but has a random number in a set position

Comment: It is not clear at all what the requirements are. If you just need to replace a chunk of digits, your regex is a mere `[0-9]+`. If you must check the characters before and after, what are they? Letters? Any non-digits? If there are several digit chunks in a string, which one to match? You say the digits may be missing - then how to find the location where to insert the `replaced` substring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it using this regex

```
String\d*Containing
```

replace it with (1st group)replaced(2nd Group)

see the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pSsbcH/3)

Comment: Thanks for your help but this just replaces the number. I need the substring eg "String7Containing" or "String6Containg" repalced byt "replaced. So you would end up with "IAmArepalcedChars"

Comment: Downvote wasn't me. I've also picked up 3 unexplained downvotes on my question...